# Python save data from columns into variables

Tags: python

Beginner in python here. I am working with distance sensors using a Rapsberry Pi and Arduino.
The output of the sensor data is continuous until the program is stopped. Here is a snippet of the output:

```
4 5 5 0 0 448
4 5 5 0 0 0
4 5 5 0 0 0
4 5 5 0 0 0
4 5 5 0 0 0
4 5 5 0 0 0
4 5 5 0 0 448
```

The question I have is what would be the best way to save each column of data into its own variable? Each column is its own sensor separated by a space and I need to perform operations on each sensor. I have attempted using `.split()` but am unable to get it to function properly.

Here is the python code that will get the serial data from the Arduino. If I didn't use the `.decode()` and `.strip()` then the output would have a b' on the beginning of each newline and a `/r/n` on the end of each newline.

```
import datetime
import serial
datetime.datetime.now()
ser=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',115200)

while True:
    read_serial=ser.readline()
    val= read_serial.decode()
    print (val.strip())
```

Here is the Arduino code:

```cpp
#include <NewPing.h>
#define SONAR_NUM 6    // Number of sensors.
#define MAX_DISTANCE 500 // Maximum distance (in cm) to ping.


NewPing sonar[SONAR_NUM] = {   // Sensor object array.
  NewPing(12, 13, MAX_DISTANCE), // Each sensor's trigger pin, echo pin, and max distance to ping. 
  NewPing(10, 11, MAX_DISTANCE), 
  NewPing(8, 9, MAX_DISTANCE),
  NewPing(6, 7, MAX_DISTANCE),
  NewPing(4, 5, MAX_DISTANCE),
  NewPing(2, 3, MAX_DISTANCE)
};

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200); // Open serial monitor at 115200 baud to see ping results.
}

void loop() { 
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < SONAR_NUM; i++) { // Loop through each sensor and display results.
    delay(15); // Wait 50ms between pings (about 20 pings/sec). 29ms should be the shortest delay between pings    
    Serial.print(" "); 
    Serial.print(sonar[i].ping_in());
  }
  Serial.println();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I didn't use the .decode() and .strip() then the ouput would have a b' on the beginning of each newline and a /r/n on the end of each newline.

```
read_serial=ser.readline()
```

This line is returning bytes. In Python 3, the decode function will decode a byte string to UTF-8 by default. It looks like you are dealing with integers so decoding isn't necessary.

```
val.strip()
```

This removes the line-feeds and other white-space characters from both ends. It may be better to simply use rstrip since that is where the line-feeds are located.

Once you have read the line and have stripped line-feeds, you can then use split to create an array for your values. Example:

```
val = b'4 5 5 0 0 448'
row = [int(x) for x in val.split()]
```

The row variable now contains 6 values that you can access using row[i] where i is the position of the value (starting with 0).

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: This works for the first three indexes row[0], row[1], row[2]. But when I go to row [3] or above i get list index out of range error.

Comment: `read_serial=ser.readline()` 

Does this always return 6 things? Can you print(row) and show the output?

Comment: If I print just read_serial without stripping I get: b' 4 5 0 0 3\r\n'. If I print(row) the output is in the form of a list: ['4','5','6','64','22','12']

Comment: Ok, so the list has 6 elements in it -- so you should be able to access row[3] which is the 4'th element. Can you confirm print(row) always returns 6? The list looks correct so I'm confused why you can't access the 4'th element.

Comment: I think I see the issue. When it printed the first line sometimes only one value will appear. I just ran it agin and watched it for a few seconds and the output is this:     ['0']                                                                                                                                         ['4','5','6','64','22','12']. I think I would need to delay the readings, maybe that would solve this issue?

Comment: I ran it again and the first line that is read had three values but every new line after that has 6 values. So we need to skip the first line that is read?

Comment: It sounds like it is outputting some type of data frames where maybe a line with 3 values is the start of a new frame. What you could do is test the length of row and you would know what type of data that line contains.

For example:

`if len(row) == 3:`

` ... # this is a 3 value line -- put code here to deal with that`

`elif len(row) == 6:`

`... # this is a 6 value line -- put code here to deal with that`

(Sorry for the formatting, but it's hard to do code blocks in comments)

Comment: (Also, if you included the model # of the sensor, it would help)

Comment: Great, got it to function properly. Appreciate the help Jason!

Comment: I am using an HC-sr04 sensor. But after I added the if len(row) ==6: it works.

Comment: Great!  Good luck!